# Reference for critical exponents in a non standard derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, specific-reference, critical-phenomena

I'm currently preparing an individual project about Landau theory of phase transitions. I think I understand well enough the standard procedure:

- expand the free energy as $F(P, T, \phi) = F_0(P, T) + a(P, T) \phi^2 + b(P, T)\phi^4$, where $\phi$ is the order parameter;
- find the stationary points using $\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}\phi} = 0$, that yields $\phi_0 = 0, \sqrt{\frac{-a}{2b}}$ (when the latter exists);
- assume $a\simeq A(T-T_c)$ and $b\simeq b_0$ near $T_c$;
- find the critical exponents of the various relevant quantities: $\phi, C_p, \chi$ and so on;

In particular, in this case one finds that the entropy goes as $S = -\frac{\mathrm{d}F}{\mathrm{d}T} = S_0 + \frac{A^2}{b_0}(T-T_c)$. With this approach one can also study the effect of a small external field coupled with the order parameter.

My problem is the following: I've been asked to study what happens when the first non-zero order in the expansion of $F$ is the 6th instead of the 4th, so that $F\simeq F_0 + a\phi^2 + c\phi^6$.
I'm trying to follow the standard procedure and I'm finding what I believe are good results, finding different critical exponents and so on. However, I'm struggling to find a reference of any kind for this kind of problem. I'm looking for a book, an article, really anything that addresses this problem. Even a simple list of the new critical exponents without a derivation would do, at least I could know if I'm on the right track or not.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me gain some insight about this problem!

Comment: You can use the equations to describe a [tricritical point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricritical_point). Check out for example the MF exercise sheet of [Tong’s course on SFT](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html)

Comment: @LPZ thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. However, the exercise sheet doesn't include solutions, and I can't really find them online. If you have a link to those as well, it would be great. Thanks again.